# double html elements update using Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a php page with a human user test, a text area and a form submit button. At first, the submit button is `disabled`.

Here is the logic: if the human test is passed, a text span is updated with a success message, which works perfectly. Moreover, I would like to also enable the submit button dynamically. Both html update operations are done using Ajax. The first one, with the success message works, the second update of the button fails, the innerHtml is not updated. I use a js function to handle Ajax. The test to pass is a simple addition, verifying `val_in` against `sum` :

```
function loadResult(val_in, sum) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         document.getElementById("einstein").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      var url = "";
      if (val_in == sum) {
          url = "../ajax/einstein.html";
      } else {
          url = "../ajax/sum_err.html";
      }
      xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
      xhttp.send();

      var xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         document.getElementById("submitb").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      var url2 = "";
      if (val_in == sum) {
          url2 = "../ajax/submit_button.html";
      } else {
          return;
      }
      xhttp2.open("POST", url2, true);
      xhttp2.send();

};
```

So, does someone have an idea why the second Ajax request does not work? Or maybe I shouldn't do this in this manner, I don't know. Thank you in advance :-)

/cr!ptal

Comment: what you will get second respond? (headers ant etc.) try xhttp2 open and send function include in if (val_in == sum) {} without else { return } (it's ugly code)

Comment: the second respond returns html: ```<input id='submitb' type='submit' value='Submit comment' style='color:green'/>``` Yes I can insert the second open() send() into  the first if bracket.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I had a hint on another forum. `<input>` has no innerHtml, it made no sense. I updated the `disabled` property on click on submit. Here is the corrected code:

```
function loadResult(val_in, sum) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         document.getElementById("einstein").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      var url = "";
      if (val_in == sum) {
          url = "../ajax/einstein.html";
          **document.getElementById("submitb").disabled = false;**
      } else {
          url = "../ajax/sum_err.html";
      }
      xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
      xhttp.send();   
};
```

/cr!ptal